# Calling another function through main to open up a file

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

I was wondering if there was any way to have main call another function to open up a file that is contained in argv[ ]. I have two functions above main. One is called ReadMaze (which would read in the text file and go over error checking). The other is called PrintMaze and this one prints out a border along the maze that was read inside the other function. So then what I need to do is be able to open up the txt file and have it actually be able to go through those and print it out.

Added the code with everything to show functions and what they are doing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct QQNode {

} QUEUE;

//typedef QUEUE *PQQNode;

typedef struct CEnode {
    char cglyph;
    char cDir;
    short fVisible;  //boolean
    int iDistance;   //not needed
    QUEUE *pQXnext;        
} CELL;

typedef struct MQnode {
    CELL **ppCE;
    int iRows, iCols, iGoals, iStarts;
} MAZE;

MAZE *ReadMaze(FILE *fpInput) {
    int j, k, c, g, s;
    MAZE *pMQRet;

    if ((MAZE *)0 == (pMQRet = malloc(sizeof(MAZE)))) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (2 != fscanf(fpInput, " %d,%d\n", &pMQRet->iRows, &pMQRet->iCols)) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (2 > pMQRet->iRows || 2 > pMQRet->iCols) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    if ((CELL **)0 == (pMQRet->ppCE = malloc(sizeof(CELL *) * pMQRet->iRows))) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    // initialize goals and starts
    for (g = 0; g < pMQRet->iRows; g++) {
        //Trying to initialize the starts and goals right here
    }

    for (j = 0; j < pMQRet->iRows; j++) {
        if ((CELL*)0 == (pMQRet->ppCE[j] = malloc(sizeof(CELL) * pMQRet->iCols + 1))) {
            exit(-1);
        }

        for (k = 0; k < pMQRet->iCols + 1; k++) {
            if (EOF == (c = fgetc(fpInput))) {
                exit(-1);
            }
            pMQRet->ppCE[j][k].cglyph = c;
        }
    }
    return pMQRet;
}

void PrintMaze(FILE *fpout, MAZE *pMQThis) {
    int j, k, l;
    CELL *pCE;

    if ((MAZE *)0 == pMQThis) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (l = 0; l < pMQThis->iCols + 2; l++) {
        fputc('-', fpout);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < pMQThis->iRows; j++) {
        pCE = pMQThis->ppCE[j];

        fputc('|', fpout);

        for (k = 0; k < pMQThis->iCols; k++) {
            fputc(pCE[k].cglyph, fpout);
        }

        fputc('|', fpout);
        fputc('\n', fpout);
    }

    for (l = 0; l < pMQThis->iCols + 2; l++) {
        fputc('-', fpout);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

} // end of main
```

Comment: Yes it is very possible. Clearly there is something you don't understand. But we can't help you if you don't tell us precisely what that is.

Comment: Yes, sounds perfectly normal/reasonable to me.

Comment: @kaylum If I have a function called ReadMaze(FILE *fpInput) then another one called PrintMaze(FILE *fpout, MAZE *pMQThis). The ReadMaze reads in my text files and checks for errors and the PrintMaze prints out a border around the maze it read in I am just curious how I could call one of these to open up the file through argv[ ].

Comment: The reverse comparison style `if ((MAZE *)0 == pMQThis)` is not elegant.  Use a more direct style `if (pMQThis == NULL)` or `if (!pMQThis)` and configure the compiler with appropriate warnings to detect the potential `=` / `==` confusion. (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` does the trick).

Answer (score 0):

You can call any function from `main` and pass individual command line arguments, `argv[i]` or the array itself `argv`, or even a pointer to one of its elements.  Just define the functions to take the appropriate argument type.

Your functions can be called from `main` this way:

```
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fpin = stdin;
    FILE *fpout = stdout;
    MAZE *maze;

    if (argc > 1) {
        fpin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (fpin == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot open input file %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        fpout = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        if (fpout == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot open output file %s: %s\n", argv[2],  strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    maze = ReadMaze(fpin);
    PrintMaze(fpout, maze);
    fclose(fpin);
    fclose(fpout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would I need to manually count how many times argv[ ] is used and that is the number I call? or is there another way to program something to let me know how many argv calls I have? I have functions which point to structs and I am trying to figure out how can make it call the functions to print out the txt file after all the checks have been made. I can also provide code if needed.

Comment: @Mags: *I can also provide code if needed.*  That would be the best way to explain your goal.  So far I cannot understand what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you, still new and thought I could put it in a comment

Comment: @Mags: what is stopping you from opening the files in `main` and passing the `FILE*` streams to the functions?

Comment: @Mags: I added code to deal with command line arguments, and default to `stdin` and `stdout` if fewer than 2 are given on the command line.

Comment: I tried doing that with my txt file in the folders or even just passing it as an argument on launch through argv[ ]. For some reason it just kept saying no such file or directory even just creating another pointer to it

Comment: This definitely helps. Thank you, it is just always saying Build Succeeded, but then nothing is displayed. I am going to keep playing around with it

Comment: @Mags: it would help a lot if you printed informative error messages when you exit the program upon errors.

Comment: Okay so I have narrowed it down to my fpInput is pointing into NULL down in main. Which means I need to somehow get the pointer back up to my file, right?

Comment: @Mags: it means the file could not be open.  Look at my updated code to see how to make informative error message.